# Add two objcet under Single key NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I want to add two values under one key in ios how may i do this.

I tried this

```
[indexDic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:num] forKey:@"first"];

[indexDic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag] forKey:@"first"];
```

but display only second sender.tag value it will replace the first value how may i add this two value under first key.

help me out this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *values = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:num], @"FirstValue",
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag], @"TagValue",
                        nil];
   [indexDic setObject:values forKey:@"first"];
```

Create dictionary of those values and add it into your main dictionary, That means dictionary inside another dictionary. So you many values will be stored under one hood of Key value.

On Retrieve time you can fetch like this,

```
  NSInteger  firstValue = [[[indexDic objectForKey: @"first"] objectForKey:@"FirstValue"] intValue];
  NSInteger  tagValue =  [[[indexDic objectForKey: @"first"] objectForKey:@"TagValue"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an array of objects for the key.

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:num],
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag],nil];
[indexDic setObject:array forKey:@"first"];
```

While retrieving the values you want to access them sequentially, in the same order as inserted in the array.

Hope that helps!

Comment: keeping multiple values in an array is not better optimize solution. While your start retrieving values inside array then you may have to need iterate array. which is incredibly increase the time cost of execution. If you place heep inside heep it will reduced your execution time. Using dictionary inside dictionary you can fetch exact value without iteration and writing multiple lines code while retrieving.

Comment: True for a big data set, but here the OP knows he has only two values. Only thing he has to remember is the position of data in array. This will still be O(1) fetch, no need to iterate.